# Gem not installing on 'bundle install' after successful gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I am running into an interesting issue here. Every time I create an app in rails I am forced to update my gemfile with gem 'therubyracer'.

I have successfully run gem install therubyracer inside of the new application root directory, but then when I run bundle install therubyracer gem does not appear in the list of installed gems.

I have also successfully installed therubyracer gem inside of my default gemset within RVM and this displays when I run RVM all do gem list. However, when I create a new rails application therubyracer does not appear in the list of bundled gems.

Oddly, when I go into the new rails app directory and run gem list, THERE IT IS, therubyracer. Yet somehow if I run bundle install, therubyracer still doesn't appear in my list of bundled/installed gems.

I feel that I may be going mad. Please help =)

Comment: Please show us the exact commands you are running. From your question, due to the lack of punctuation, it is difficult to tell if you're using `bundle install therubyracer` or just simply `bundle install`.

Comment: As far as I know if the gem is not listed in your Gemfile it will not be installed with `bundle install` moreover it will not be loaded when you start rails server.

Answer (score 1):

Such type of problems appear often you have successfully install RVM.So you should create

separate gemset directory every time for new application rather than use global gemset

directory.Then this type of problems will never occur.

```
  rvm gemset create blog
```

then you should use this gemset directory and also ruby version as well e.g you have

install ruby 1.9.2 then use this command

```
  rvm use ruby-1.9.2@blog
```

after that go into directory of blog application and install this gem

```
  gem install bundler
```

and also then bundle install. so all local gem will be installed into this blog directory

under rvm and there will be no conflicts will be appear.